# Team Foundation Server rules and client side validation

Tags: tfs

We are trying to ensure that all users follow the rules of ALM when using Team Foundation Server. For example, to ensure that work items and their children have consistent states. Specifically, when transitioning a User Story to the "Closed" state, this should only be allowed if all of the children tasks are closed. Is there any way to implement this behavior with TFS?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified which TFS and VS you are using so I am going to assume 2013, although explanations are the same for 2012.

I don't think you can achieve your goal by just configuration, you may need to write some code by using one of the [extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx) hooks provided by TFS.

A good place to start is to see if you can leverage the [TFS Power Tools -](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) a collection of tools (policies, templates etc.) provided by the TFS team out of band with the product itself.